# What's the difference between CPQ and CPQ plus

Tags: cpq, advanced-approvals

My company has CPQ+ but I don't think we are using any of its functionalities.
Tried to do some research on what are the differences between the 2 versions and all I could find was that CPQ+ has advance approvals.

Any other things we might miss and/or issues that you guys are aware we could have downgrading to its regular version?

Answer (score 0):

Here are few benefits of CPQ Plus.

1. Configuration, Pricing and Quoting
2. Enhanced Product Catalog and Price Book
3. Advanced approvals and order management
4. Usage based pricing

It has increased process control and automation.

Check few benefits of CPQ plus upgrade listed  [here](https://www.saasguru.co/cpq-plus-upgrades-in-salesforce-summer-23-release/).